# log4net not inserting into database but working fine for file

Tags: wcf, log4net

I am using this code in WCF application in VS 2012, SQL Express is 2008 R2.

I have included the fileAppendor and Database Appendor, File Appender works fine but its not inserting data into the database.

I have verified the same connection string its working fine and inserting records in to the table.

Also I have set the buffer value to 1, still no luck

```
<bufferSize value="1" />
```

This is my config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>    

  <log4net>

    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Log_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=360;" />
      <connectionString value="data source=[(local)\\SQLEXPRESS];initial catalog=[Log_DB];integrated security=SSPI" />

      <commandText value="INSERT INTO [Error_Log] ([Date_time] ) VALUES (@Date_time)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Date_time" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <!--<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />-->
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
      </parameter>
             </appender>

    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
       <file value="log-file.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] ID=%property{EventID} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
 ...

</configuration>
```

Do I am missing any other stuff?

Also I am not getting any information by setting Internal.Debug to true. 
How to get internal debug details of log4net?

Answer (score 2):

Finaly I got the answer for this, I am sharing here since it may help others.

Need to use the **System/Machine Name** instead of **(local)** in the Connection string. Even with the dotnet application (local) works but for log4net need to use the System name.